# Multithreading in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have the next sample of code in JavaScript:

```js
var i = 0;

async function asyncFunction() {
  i++;
  document.write(i + "<br/>");
}

for (var j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
  asyncFunction();
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>
<body>

</body>

</html>
```

The Output in The Google Chrome is:

```
1
2
3
4
...
1000
```

It isn't:

```
1
3
2
4
...
1000
999
```

I am using The Google Chrome and It's always syncronius. When Is It planned be able?

Comment: if your function have prefix "async" then inside should have "await"

Comment: If it was always using with await then It isn't async.

Comment: also, javascript is single threaded

Comment: Because your for loop is synchronous. It calls asyncFunction one by one from 0 to 999. And i is increased in every call. Because you see i in ordered in your results.

Comment: @Jaromanda-X I don't have an idea for what is the async command and difference between a native function and async in JavaScript.

Comment: `async` allows you to `await` inside the function, and results in the function returning a `Promise`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *async*, isn't a tool to acquire multithreading, it's for acquiring single-threaded concurrency. If you want to learn how to do multithreading, look up WebWorkers (for developing in browsers), or Node Cluster API (for NodeJS).

Output of the code is sorted:

1. Because by calling an async function, you put it on a microtasks queue, and after the loop is finished, it's being called one by one in the same order as it has been placed.
2. Order of calling for this function doesn't matter as each invocation increases the i by +1 regardless of the order.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `document.write` [unless you know *exactly* what it does](http://pomax.github.io/1473270609919/if-you-use-use-document-write-you-suck-at-javascript) (which almost no one does because it's an insanely low level pipe function directly into the byte stream that's open *while your document parses*, and should in retrospect never have been a public function). Use `console.log`.

Having said that: look at what your function does: it is literally impossible for it to print anything other a monotonic sequence, because you're using a *global* value `i`.

Every time asyncFunction runs, it takes "Whatever `i` is", increments it and runs your low level document byte data write instruction (which, again, you shouldn't be using). Inside the function, your code is synchronous, so the JS thread *has* to execute all your statement before it's free to pick some next scheduled call.

As such, each call gets `i`, increments it, writes, ends. A next function resolves, but *irrespective of which one it was* it will get that previously incremented `i`, increments it, writes it out, and then ends. 1 becomes 2 becomes 3 becomes 4 and so forth until your for loop ends.

Comment: How Can I do an multithreading? Why The code with async equals to the code without async?

Comment: async doesn't make the function asyncrhonous

Comment: JS can't do multi threading. You only get a single thread, and you can "defer execution of functions" to whenever the JS engine has time to run something by using the `async` keyword. The only thing `async` does is mark a function for _asynchronous_ execution (by wrapping it in a  `Promise` and returning that) rather than _immediate_ execution (returning the execution result). It doesn't magically change the JS execution model from single-threaded to multi-threaded.